# Javascript- addEventListener

Tags: javascript

Greeting for some reason my -addEventListener is not executing when I click the button. Can anyone help this is my code:

```
function elNegro() {
    alert("Thank You For Your Subscription!");
}

var week = document.getElementById("get");
week.addEventListener("click", elNegro);
```

Comment: press `ctrl + shift + j` to see if there is any javascript error in your browser.

Comment: I would suggest that you choose longer and more descriptive ids for you elements.

Answer (score 2):

The code works fine. Check the snippet. You may have javascript disabled for your browser. Ensure it is enabled and check for parenthesis for the code you are writing. Also, make sure the element with id `get` is present in your HTML.

```js
function elNegro() {
   alert("Thank You For Your Subscription!");
}

var week = document.getElementById("get");
week.addEventListener("click", elNegro);
```

```html
<div>
<button id='get'>Get Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad to help you. Please mark it green if it was really helpful to you